# Entity framework falling over

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I publish my website and put it on the live server the site falls over with the error below. The code works fine localy in visual studio and I have checked my server has connectivity to the database. The entity data model is in the APP_code file. Possibly that is wrong? Thanks

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
App_Code.portal.msl(26,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.DateTimeOffset[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=]' of member 'updated' in type 'fldtportalModel.accounting_traffic' is not compatible with 'MySql.timestamp[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=0]' of member 'updated' in type 'fldtportalModel.Store.accounting_traffic'.
```

**EDIT** Just to clarify im using exactly the same databse on live and on my local.

Comment: Does your local database schema match that on production?

Comment: @Ian Nelson yes. Its the same database

Comment: You have a version problem, either with your Db or your code. Something is not up-to-date. Tell us the what column-type `updated` has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you read the exception message?

Your `DateTimeOffset` field in the model is not compatible with the `timestamp` field in the database.

Comment: Probably because the schema or MySQL DLL version is different.

Comment: Its using the same DLL and schema. Exactly the same code using the same db works fine before i compile the site.

Comment: @TomSquires: You are very sure that they are the same. All the more reason to check it. Check it twice, check versions, file-sizes and timestamps and use a diff tool on the exported schema's.

Comment: @SLaks I ended up setting the data provider explicitly in the web config. That worked. There was an earlier version in the GAC, I can only presume it was picking that up for some reason. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even I had got a similar error

> > Error 2   Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Int32[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 'AllowedProjects' in type 'VanillaBugsDbModel.CompanyProfile' is not compatible with 'MySql.smallint[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 'allowedProjects' in type 'VanillaBugsDbModel.Store.companyprofile'.  C:\Yasser\projects\Vanilla Bugs\trunk\src\VanillaBugs.Service\Data\MySql\VanillaBugs.edmx   515 17  VanillaBugs.Service

Thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647437/entity-framework-falling-over#comment9290403_7647472) on the marked answer I was able to get this fixed.

It was probably because the schema or MySQL DLL version is different.